# powershell 7 can't install module by install-module command

Tags: powershell, powerbi, import-module

I installed latest powershell 7 on my laptop windows 10 enterprise;
tried to install a module by: `install-module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt` but
got below error;
Any information is much appreciated.

[image: error screenshot]

I tried to follow the prompts to install "NuGet provider", but also getting errors.

thanks mklement0 providing the information for install-psresource;
But why install-module is not working in my powershell 7? tried to figure this out, is it because I have both powershell 5.1 and powershell 7 installed? see below "get-module -ListAvailable PowerShellGet" output.

[image]

Comment: I have no explanation, but since you're using PowerShell (Core) 7.4.1, you can try `Install-PSResource MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt` instead (don't know if it'll make a difference.

Comment: @mklement0, wow, Install-PSResource is working, big thanks, but why install-module is not working anymore?

Comment: Glad to hear it, Victory. `Install-PSResource` is the successor to `Install-Module`, albeit only for PowerShell resources, and only it is actively maintained. `Install-Module` still generally works, however, and your specific command does work on my machine - not sure what's happening on yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no explanation for your specific symptom, but per your feedback using
`Install-PSResource MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt` instead of
`Install-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt`  solved the problem.

- **`Install-PSResource`, from the [`PSResourceGet`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSResourceGet) module, is the successor to `Install-Module`** and **ships with [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) 7.4+**.

  - However, **you can install it on demand** [from the PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet) in older versions, including Windows PowerShell, too (e.g., with
    `Install-Module Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet`)
  - *At some point in the future*, Windows itself will ship with this module so that it will be available by default in Windows PowerShell too - see [this PowerShell Team blog post](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.PSResourceGet) for more information.
- **Unlike `Install-Module`, `Install-PSResource` is actively maintained**, and is worth trying whenever specific `Install-Module` calls fail.