Powershell Install-Module not working properly
I am trying to follow this extremely easy example    https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/install-power-bi-powershell-in-your-windows-machine/       but it does not seem to work. What could be the causes?


What happens if you run Get-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -All -ListAvailable?

Somethings seems to run for like 10 seconds, and I receive no reply. What should I expect to see?

Get-Module shows the modules on your machine.  Adding MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt will filter this for just that module.  ListAvailable says to not only list the modules already loaded (imported) in the current session, but all those that are available (installed).  All says to return all versions of the installed modules; not just the defaults.  So if Install-Module had worked you'd expect it to show in the output here, even if there's an issue loading it.  It doesn't fix things for you - just gives you evidence to help pin down where the issue may be.

Not sure what your issue is in this case, but you may want to look at this answer (for PS Core; i.e. >=v6) for an alternative approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77829058/361842

Look at my answer in the question here. That is exactly what you are facing.
INSTALL-MODULE Not working
Also, check first if the module is available or not
Get-Module MicrosoftPowerBIMgmt -All -ListAvailable

Thanks for your answer. Get-Module returns nothing... I also tried downloading it manually but I get a .nupkg file

Thats fine. You can install .nupkg easily. Follow Installing PowerShell modules from a NuGet package
